# Pre Populate custom field while creating a new record

Tags: lightning, urlhacking

I am trying to pre-populate a `lookup` field while creating a new `Account` record and as per documentation we can use field name instead of custom fieldId.

**Classic Way:**

```
https://test--dev.my.salesforce.com/a06/e?
CF00N71000001zWxy=Test+User
&CF00N71000001zWxy_lkid=0010500000IZ8jXAAT
```

**New Way**

```
https://test--dev.lightning.force.com/lightning/o/Account/new?defaultFieldValues=
Client__c=0010500000IZ8jXAAT
```

Is there any way we can pre-populate Text for a lookup field in lightning just in the same way we used to do `CF00N71000001zWxy=Test+User`

Answer (score 0):

I created a new button on the Account object to create the contact which prepopulate the Account look up.

The **Custom Account Name** field is a custom look up field for the account object.

See if this helps for you.

[image]

[image]